# The fact that she "would/will" come to see me on Friday bothered me. - "the fact that..." follows the rule of sequence of tense?

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

Assume the time of speaking is on Wednesday and the time of action of bothering happened way back, last week.

**Example 1**

> The fact that she **would** come to see me on Friday bothered me.

**Example 2**

> The fact that she **will** come to see me on Friday bothered me.

Which example is correct?

Does the tense in the appositive have to follow the rule of tense sequence?

Answer (score 3):

If the 'bothering' happened last week, presumably you mean that the visit was last Friday, so *would* is appropriate. (It was in the future then but is now in the past.)

We would only use *will* if the visit hasn't happened yet.